# How to paste excel data table into outlook through vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Dim rngAttach As Range

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With ActiveSheet
    Set rngTo = Sheets("Helpdesk Data").Range("D4")
    Set rngSubject = Sheets("Helpdesk Data").Range("I5")
    'Set rngBody = Sheets("Helpdesk Data").Range("D4")
    'Set rngAttach = .Range("B4")

     End With

Sheets("Helpdesk Data").Select
Sheets("Helpdesk Data").Range("B12:Z12").Select
Sheets("Helpdesk Data").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Now I want to paste above copied data from "Helpdesk data" into Outlook Body, but don't know how to do it.. I tried Specialpaste with Outlook object but it also dispays errors..

```
With objMail
    '.To = rngTo.Value
    .Subject = "Owner Issue at Site " & rngSubject.Value & " - (" & rngTo.Value & " Circle)"
    .Body = "Sir, " & _
    "Please find below site issue reported Today."

    '.Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
    .Display

End With

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set rngTo = Nothing
Set rngSubject = Nothing
Set rngBody = Nothing
Set rngAttach = Nothing

End Sub
```

So anyone could tell me just how could i paste my B12 to Z12 data from "Helpdesk data" sheet to outlook body..

Comment: try .Body = "Sir, " & _
    "Please find below site issue reported Today." & vbnewline & selection

Comment: Now it shows type mismatch error at .body line..

Comment: It is something like that try selection.value

Comment: I tried to copy and special paste a single cell data then it works perfectly but i want to paste a range of data with table and pre formatting with which it not working..

Comment: You could make it an HTML Mail Item and then pull the cell values one by one into an HTML formatted table. The attachments.add only works with files so to add it as an atachment you could copy it into a new workbook and then attach that workbook in the email

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use the `.HTMLBody` property and to turn the required range into HTML formatting.

In your e-mail sub, with your `objMail`, include the `.HTMLBody` property and pass a range into the `rngHTML` function.

`.HTMLBody = "Table below." & vbNewLine & rngHTML(Range("A1:B10"))`

Include the function which will generate the HTML range in your code.

```
Function rngHTML(Rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, TempWB As Workbook
    Dim TempFile As String

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    '' copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data into
    Rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    '' publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    '' read all data from the htm file into rngHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    rngHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    rngHTML = Replace(rngHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    '' delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Please see [Ron de Bruin's](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) website, this is where I originally came across this function; he also explains another method of getting a range into the body of an e-mail.

Hope this helps.