# How can I refer a hyperlink to a cell value in the body of an email?

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink

I would like to hyperlink a cell and have the value of that cell be the hyperlink in the body of the email.

So in below's code instead of "Hello" it should refer to value of a cell. Say if Range("A1") equals 100, the hyperlink in the body of the email should say 100. If I change Range("A1") to 101, the hyperlink in the email should change to 101.

Thanks for your help!

My code:

```
Sub SendHyperlinkEmail()

    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

        Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = "<A HREF='mailto:z@zzz.com'>Hello</A>"


        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Test
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set outApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `strbody = "<A HREF='mailto:z@zzz.com'>" & Range("A1").Text & "</A>"`

Comment: @VincentG you should add that as an answer with some text to clarify what you're doing to accomplish what the OP is asking. I'm curious to know as well.

Comment: Worked perfectly - many thanks. Just a final question,  what if i have a table, i.e. Range("A1:B4")?

Answer (score 0):

I think concatenation would work.

```
strbody = "<A HREF='mailto:z@zzz.com'>" & range("a1") & "</A>"
```

"&" is used in VBA to concatenate text and variables/ranges/etc

Comment: Many thanks -work fine. Do you happen to know how I can include a range? So instead of range("A1") I would like range("A1:B4")?

Comment: That depends on what type of data you have in the range and whether it should be concatenated with or without a separator. Can you give an example?

Comment: @ Mr ML - values are simple fixed numeric values and these values should be in table format. Therefore a white space between values and a new line for each row in the table. I was hoping changing range("A1") to range ("A1:B4") would do the job but get a Type Mismatch.

Comment: That is not a simple task. You could do it the easy way and concatenate the line 1 by 1. (Range("A1") & Range("A2") & .. & Range("B4")). Else this function is what your seeking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453759/how-to-paste-excel-data-table-into-outlook-through-vba

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to get a fairly ugly solution myself so open for improvement:

Sub SendHyperlinkEmail()

```
Dim outApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "<table>" & "<tr>" & "<A 
HREF='mailto:mailto:z@zzz.com?subject=Enquiry&Body=I would 
like to'>" _
& range("B2") & "&nbsp;" & range("C2") & "</A>" & "</tr>" & 
 _ "<tr>" & "<A HREF='mailto:mailto:z@zzz.com 
  subject=Enquiry&Body=I would like to'>" _
 & range("B3") & "&nbsp;" & range("C3") & "</A>" & "</tr>" & _
    "<tr>" & "<A HREF='mailto:mailto:z@zzz.com?subject=Enquiry&Body=I would like to'>" _
    & range("B4") & "&nbsp;" & range("C4") & "</A>" & "</tr>" & _
    "</table>"On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Test
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set outApp = Nothing
```

End Sub